# Perl: compare lines in an xml file

Tags: xml, perl

I've got an xml file which looks a bit like this:

```
<root>
  <project id="1">
    <element name="stuff" version="1.0"/>
    <element name="stuff" version="1.2"/>
    <element name="table" version="0.8"/>
  </project>
  <project id="2">
    <element name="fruit" version="1.0"/>
    <element name="tree" version="1.2"/>
    <element name="tree" version="0.8"/>
    <element name="tree" version="2.5"/>
  </project>
</root>
```

What I would like to is to delete all the elements with inferior version numbers. What I know so far is to read in the file and detect the lines which contain the elements:

```
open(FILE, "<file.xml"); 
my @line = <FILE>; 
close(FILE); 
open(FILE, ">file.xml"); 
foreach my $line (@line) {
  if (index ($line, '<element') != -1) {
    #only print newer versions here
  }
}
```

But now I am not sure how to go on. I know I can compare version numbers like this: `version->parse($variable1) < version->parse($variable2)` but how can I compare two lines of the same file and then delete the one with the older version number?

Comment: Use an XML parser

Comment: I heartily recommend the XML::LibXML library and have written a [tutorial with lot of examples](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

#set a handler for 'element' - this just collects the highest 'versions'.
my %version_of; 
sub get_highest_version {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_; 
    my $name = $element -> att('name'); 
    my $version = $element -> att('version'); 
    if ( not defined $version_of{$name}
         or $version_of{$name} < $version ) {
            $version_of{$name} = $version; 
    }
}

#create a parser, set it to use the above handler for 'element' elements. 
my $twig = XML::Twig->new ( twig_handlers => { 'element' => \&get_highest_version } );
#parse the data (in __DATA__ below - you probably want to use 'parsefile' instead)
$twig -> parse( \*DATA );

#output for debug - see what the highest versions of each actually were. 
print Dumper \%version_of;

#iterate each of the 'element' nodes. 
foreach my $element ( $twig -> get_xpath ('//element') ) {
    #extract name/version from this element. 
    my $name = $element -> att('name'); 
    my $version = $element -> att('version');
    #delete this node unless it's the highest version.  
    $element -> delete unless $version >= $version_of{$name}; 
}

#set output indentation and print
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;


__DATA__
<root>
  <project id="1">
    <element name="stuff" version="1.0"/>
    <element name="stuff" version="1.2"/>
    <element name="table" version="0.8"/>
  </project>
  <project id="2">
    <element name="fruit" version="1.0"/>
    <element name="tree" version="1.2"/>
    <element name="tree" version="0.8"/>
    <element name="tree" version="2.5"/>
  </project>
</root>
```

Although note - this does mean you *might* see duplicates if you have two equal versions. It also ignores the 'project' hierarchy entirely - it looks for global highest versions. (You could do this quite easily by tracking the project-id though)

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool. For example, I maintain [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for my $project in /root/project {
    for my $element in $project/element {
        if ($element/@version 
            != xsh:max($element/../element[@name=$element/@name]/@version)
        ) delete $element ;
    }
}
save :b ;
```

If there are many versions per name, it might be faster to compute the maximum in advance:

```
for my $project in /root/project {
    my $versions := hash ../@name $project/element/@version ;
    for my $name in { keys %$versions } {
        my $max = xsh:max(xsh:lookup('versions', $name)) ;
        delete $project/element[@name = $name][@version != $max] ;
    }
}
```